# Does this model make any sense?

Tags: arima

I have fitted data of user activity per day to an arima(1,0,1)x(1,0,0).

It's a nice fit. But does it make any sense?

Comment: Well, it could certainly make sense, indeed such a model is relatively easily understood and interpreted; whether it does make sense in your particular application depends on what the application is.

Comment: That is reassuring. What is the interpretation if you would indulge me? The data is originally minute-wise user interaction that I've aggregated per day, over 25 weeks. So there is a weekly cycle and there also a noticable dip approaching summer.

Comment: Well, maybe you could post some plots?